# Loopback: Passing multiple object types in a remote method

Tags: object, arguments, loopbackjs, overwrite, strongloop

I have an issue where when I pass two object types as a remote method argument, the first argument gets overwritten by the second argument. Below is code and results. How could I go about not having the second argument not overwrite the first argument?

```
module.exports = (Model) => {
  Model.calculate = (primary, secondary) => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(primary, null, 2));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(secondary, null, 2));

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({ Model: calculator.calculate() });
    });
  };

  Model.remoteMethod('calculate', {
    accepts: [
      { arg: 'primary', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' } },
      { arg: 'secondary', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' } }
    ],
    returns: {arg: 'Result', type: 'string'}
  });
};
```

When I pass in the primary argument 
{
  "name": "Tom"
} and secondary argument
{
  "name: "Joe"
}
after console logging the JSON objects primary and secondary I get the result.

```
primary 
{
  "name": "Joe" <--- WHY?!
}

secondary 
{
  "name: "Joe"
}
```

As you can see Tom was overwritten to Joe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change:

```
Model.remoteMethod('calculate', {
    accepts: [
      { arg: 'primary', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' } },
      { arg: 'secondary', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' } }
    ],
    returns: {arg: 'Result', type: 'string'}
  });
```

to:

```
Model.remoteMethod('calculate', {
    accepts: [
      { arg: 'primary', type: 'object' },
      { arg: 'secondary', type: 'object' }
    ],
    returns: {arg: 'Result', type: 'string'}
  });
```

`http: { source: 'body' }` sends in the whole body of html as the object value, so you are sending that in, twice - it looks like a form field called `name` is what is being picked up, but provide more code if this isn't the case.

[More info on optional HTTP mapping of input arguments here.](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods#Remotemethods-HTTPmappingofinputarguments) But the main thing to note is that it is optional :-)

Comment: Thanks! It Worked! :)